# How do I turn $y$ in this equation as an input ? $\sqrt{y^3} = x - 7$

Tags: functions

I am trying to turn $y$ as an input but I somehow hit a wall, I tried $$y = \sqrt[3]{(x-7)^2}$$ but somehow it did not work. Any tips ?

Comment: Swap $x<->y$ to get $x=(y-7)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: squaring the whole equation $$y^3=(x-7)^2$$ therefore $$y=\sqrt[3]{(x-7)^2}$$
in the opposite direction we get $$y^3=(x-7)^2$$ terefore $$y^{3/2}=|x-7|$$for $$x\geq 7$$ we get $$x=y^{3/2}+7=x$$ or in the othere case
$$y^{3/2}=-x+7$$ therefore $$x=7-y^{3/2}$$

Comment: +1 but the word hint is hardly a good description for a full solution

Comment: the word in the sence solving the Problems in future

Comment: Normally squaring runs the risk of introducing extraneous solutions.  Here the original problem guarantees us that $y \ge 0$ so that is not a problem.

Comment: this is absolutely true.

Comment: The Op said y for *input*.  So we want x = f(y).  Not f(x) = y.

Answer (score 2):

Putting "y as input" means making a function $x = f(y)$.

So solve for $x$.

$\sqrt{y^3} = x - 7 \implies$

$x = \sqrt{y^3} + 7$.

... and that's all there is to it.

(Note: $y$ must be positive. and $x \ge 7$.  That was true in the first equation as well.)